# 500 - Internal Server Error ASP.NET (IIS 7.5)

Tags: windows, azure, iis-7.5, dotnetnuke

I am now in the process of transferring my servers to windows azure. I created a virtual machine  (`2008 R2`) and installed `IIS 7.5`. I then transferred one of the site (`DNN`) and configured it to with it's own `apppool` (4.0) and granted permission for this app pool to read and write.

I have two domains: one internal, which I defined in the HOST file, and one public (mydomain.com). The internal domain works fine however with the external domain I'm getting:

> 500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you
>   are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Comment: Try viewing the website on the actual server (if you haven't already), you usually find a better error message that way, and that may help you further determine what the problem is.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning that but I did try everything on the server itself but I don't get the details for the error.

Comment: in web.config, make '<CustomErrors Mode="Off">' and '<Compilation debug="true"...\>'

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you haven't set up endpoints for the server on the portal to allow HTTP traffic? In other words, did you open up port 80 on the Azure portal for this VM?

Check out how to do that here - https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/how-to-guides/setup-endpoints/

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I did everything right as you guys describe here and doubled checked it but nothing worked. Eventually I decided to restart the server and the problem solved. Go figure...